# Автоматическая live загрузка Debian с usb

Tags: debian, usb, live

Есть live образ Debian на SD карте, при загрузке компьютера, выходит меню выбора (лайв, установить и т.д). Вопрос, как миновать это окно и сразу бутить лайв версию? Делается это для того, что бы если вдруг комп выключился, он не застопорился на этом окне при запуске. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Выставить в BIOS приоритет загрузки для SD-карты. Так-же, наверняка в вашем биос, включена функция «показывать меню выбора загрузки».

Comment: Проблема в том, что не BIOS предлагает этот выбор, а сам Debian при загрузке

Comment: Ага. У вас там лайв образ или уже установленная система?

Comment: лайв образ. debian-live-10.2.0-i386-cinnamon.iso

Comment: Тогда -- загружаетесь с карточки и редактируете `/etc/default/grub` Так как указано на этом [скрине](https://i.imgur.com/FSpHvsn.png). Только `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` и говорите волшебное `sudo grub-mkconfig`

Comment: К сожалению, такого файла там нет. Есть только папака grub.d с init-select.cfg. Где только комментарий, что, мол, этот файл ничего не делает.